# Rails storing form data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I am trying to take the query from a search form, store it in a variable, and pass it as the query to the twitter api, but I'm afraid I am confused about how to store the input. I have the form set up in layouts/application.html.erb

```
  <%= form_tag(:method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  <% end %>
```

But that is really it, I am not sure how to save the input, and when I click the search button, there is a routing error "no route matches "[POST] /pages/home"

Comment: The first option for form tag is the url.. which you have not provided

Comment: @sethi so what should it be?

Comment: What is the controller/action for this search? e.g. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag

Comment: @sethi im not sure, I'm really lost.

Comment: You can use the example below.

Run 'rake routes' it will give you a list of paths. Also you dont have to use the path variable you can just use the URL. You can put the output of rake routes here. Any any controller you have written to do the search,

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this

```
<%= form_tag your_path_here,:method => "get", id: "search-form" do %>
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search" %>
<%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I tried Page_path but it said it was an uninitialized constant.